# Prove that the intersection of definable sets is definable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hello I have a question :

$F$ is a family of definable sets. Prove that the intersection of all the sets in the family is definable. ($F$ could be infinite)

**Definition (Definable)**: a set $K$ of assignments is definable if there is a set of formulas A such that $\operatorname{Ass}(A) = K$.

I don't know how to approach it because F could be infinite.. I will be glad to get help.

Comment: Peculiar definition of definable, makes every set of natural numbers definable. I would restrict to a single formula, or equivalently a finite set.

Comment: This looks suspiciously similar to [this question about unions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260521/union-of-definable-sets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall A\in F$ there is a set of formulas $\Sigma_A \space s.t \space Ass(\Sigma_A)=A$  (because A is definable).
Now, lets define $\Sigma= \cup_{A\in F} \Sigma_A$.

Prove that : $Ass(\Sigma)=\cap_{A\in F} A$